# Inserir classe de web api em projeto web já existente

Tags: asp.net, api, aplicação-web

Em meu visual studio 2012, tenho uma solução com vários projetos e um deles é web. Neste projeto, gostaria de incluir uma classe "Web Api Controller" para fazer alguns testes.

Criei uma classe com o nome ValuesController, com todos os métodos necessários. Criei uma página .aspx simples e coloquei o código ajax pra fazer a chamada ao api, porém, o browser dá a resposta que não conseguiu encontrar o recurso que precisava (/View/api/Values).

Quando faço exatamente a mesma coisa em um projeto web novo, o sistema roda sem problema.

Será que alguém já enfrentou este problema ou mesmo consegue ajudar?

Segue detalhes:

Método do Global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Função Jquery para chamada do método do server:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ValuesController.cs
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste maiores detalhes do erro. Você pode criar um projeto web com especificação API fica mais fácil. A sua requisição ajax é post ou get? seu método aceita ambos? Geralmente o erro "não conseguiu encontrar o recurso que precisava" acontece por várias razões, poste o código do método. Tente limpar o projeto e reiniciar o visual studio. As vezes ele da erro na recompilação e acaba dizendo que o recurso não existe!

Comment: Opa. Então, iniciar um projeto novo não vai me adiantar, pois quero realmente fazer algumas melhorias neste que já existe. Quando crio um novo, roda sem problemas. Vou postar o código.

Comment: Poste do método que você está testando e da sua requisição ajax!

Comment: Postei, mas como tinha dito, se eu criar uma solução nova, com um projeto web e colocar exatamente o mesmo código com a mesma estrutura, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Em que momento você retorna um conteúdo json?

Comment: Premiere, obrigado pela ajuda. Meu erro estava na minha rota, que não tinha o endereço da subpasta. Meu routeTemplate devia estar assim: "View/api/{controller}/{id}". De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: O json é o data Premiere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meu erro estava em não colocar a subpasta (View) do meu arquivo aspx.cs no routeTemplate.

Meu método devia ficar assim:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "View/api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Quando você faz uma requisição com jquery, JSON, ele verifica o content-type e se o mesmo não for igual a application/json não vai ter retorno. O erro do recurso não é por esse motivo, apenas para alertar!

Se você realmente precisar usar a API dentro do projeto web app de uma olhada no WEB API SELF HOST, talvez se adeque mais as suas necessidades.

Comment: Vlw Premiere. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Depois marque essa sua resposta como a correta!